# Mageno2.4 How to customize an HTTP POST request interface

Tags: rest-api

I have an order management system. I want to notify Magento2 of the status of my order management system. I want to call Magento2 custom interface, but I do not know how to create Magento2.4 interface request. How to customize Magento2.4 HTTP POST request interface

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 has Event systems that you can add your code before or after the event run.
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html#events-in-php-files

You may use ***sales_order_place_after*** event to send the order data to your system.
https://magecomp.com/blog/get-order-status-sales_order_place_after-event-magento-2/